# Auto initialize controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've created a custom control that need to be initialized. Actually I have that function to initialize my custom control (called "UserControl_Grille") :

```
 Private Sub Init_Grille()
    Me.grilleA.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Me.grilleB.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Me.grilleC.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Me.grilleD.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Me.grilleE.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Me.grilleF.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Me.grilleG.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Me.grilleH.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
End Sub
```

As you can see it's not very worth it as If a add a new control I have to add it in this function.

So I tried to initialize automatically but it seems that it don't detect any custom control in my form ... :

```
Private Sub Init_Grille()
    For Each grille As UserControl_Grille In Me.Controls.OfType(Of UserControl_Grille)()
        grille.init_traduction(lignesTraduction)
    Next
End Sub
```

In debug mode, it direct pass throught the For Each loop. There is any other solution?

Comment: Is your control placed on the Form or inside a Panel, GroupBox or some other container?

Comment: Some other container, but it can differ... Sometime it's in a panel, another in a splitedPanel ....

Comment: There's your answer, you need to check each of the containers for controls as well. There will be a nested hierarchy of controls and containers that need to be checked for the one you are interested in.

Comment: Can you give me just a exemple to chack all containers in a foreach loop ? Another question, `Me.Controls` doesn't contain all the controls even control that are contained inside another control ?

Comment: me.Controls only holds the controls at the Form level. Each of those controls can have sub-controls (a Panel, for example, can contain other controls) so you need to scroll through those as well. I've posted a sample in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively scroll through all controls.

For example, this sample code will return a list of all Labels in your form:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ' This list will hold all the labels that we find
        Dim results As List(Of Control) = New List(Of Control)

        ' Start searching for labels at the Form level 
        FindControls(Me, results)

        ' See how many labels we have found
        MessageBox.Show(results.Count)

    End Sub

    Private Sub FindControls(parent As Control, ByRef results As List(Of Control))
        For Each control As Control In parent.Controls

            If TypeOf control Is Label Then
                ' We found a label so we add it to the results
                results.Add(control)
            End If

            If Not control.Controls Is Nothing Then
                ' We loop through all sub-controls
                FindControls(control, results)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed after JayV explanation. Thanks you